# Check if coordinates is within a specific distance from other coordinates

Tags: php, math, coordinates, match, distance

Ok, so I have a target on certain coordinates, and some 'persons' on other coordinates, and I want to check if the persons coordinates is within a 2km (2000m) distance from the target coordinates.

The code below is just to illustrate what I want more clear, and the question is of course how could this be done? I would really appreciate a solution to this one, thanks!

```
$person0 = Array('56.34342', '49.324523');
$person1 = Array('57.49544', '47.421524');
$person2 = Array('56.74612', '48.722323');

$target = Array('56.35343', '49.342343');

for (var $i = 0; $i < 4; i$++) {
    CheckIfMatch($person + i$);
}

function CheckIfMatch($person) {
    if($person is within 2km from target) {
        echo 'Match!';
    }
}
```

Comment: Google "Haversine" or "Vincenty"

Comment: have you tried [euclidean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance)  distance ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using Great Circle algorithms. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance

Here's how to find distance.

**EDIT**

Here is the full code for you to do that!

```
<?php
$persons = Array();

$persons[] = Array('52.00951','4.36052');//Delft is more than 2 km from den haag
$persons[] = Array('52.03194','4.31769');//Rijswijk is less than 2 km from den haag
$persons[] = Array('52.07097','4.29945');//A place near den Haag almost 2 streets from center and my favourite coffee shop
$persons[] = Array('52.37022','4.89517');//Amsterdamn is about 60 km *DRIVING* from the hagues according to Gmaps

$target = Array('52.07050', '4.30070');//Den Haag
$i = 0;
foreach($persons as $person){
    $i++;
    $distance = calculate_distance($person, $target);
    if($distance <= 2 ){ 
        echo "Person $i is within 2km with a distance to taget of $distance</br>";
    }else{
        echo "Person $i is <b>not</b> within 2km with a distance to taget of $distance</br>";
    }

}

function calculate_distance($person, $target){

    $lat1 = $person[0];
    $lng1 = $person[1];
    $lat2 = $target[0];
    $lng2 = $target[1];
    $pi = 3.14159;
    $rad = doubleval($pi/180.0);

    $lon1 = doubleval($lng1)*$rad;
    $lat1 = doubleval($lat1)*$rad; 
    $lon2 = doubleval($lng2)*$rad; 
    $lat2 = doubleval($lat2)*$rad; 
    $theta = $lng2 - $lng1; 

    $dist = acos(sin($lat1) * sin($lat2) + cos($lat1) * cos($lat2) * cos($theta)); 

    if ($dist < 0) 
        $dist += $pi;


    $miles = doubleval($dist * 69.1); 
    $inches = doubleval($miles * 63360); 
    $km  =  doubleval($dist * 115.1666667);

    $dist = sprintf( "%.2f",$dist); 
    $miles = sprintf( "%.2f",$miles); 
    $inches = sprintf( "%.2f",$inches); 
    $km = sprintf( "%.2f",$km);
    //Here you can return whatever you please
    return $km;
}

?>
```

And of course the results:

```
Person 1 is not within 2km with a distance to taget of 4.24
Person 2 is within 2km with a distance to taget of 1.21
Person 3 is within 2km with a distance to taget of 0.09
Person 4 is not within 2km with a distance to taget of 41.56
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I don't get the factor thing, could you explain it?

Comment: If you are using miles just replace factor with  69.1 and if km then 115.1666667. It's just for converting easiness

Comment: So, you think this should be correct? $distance = pow(((115.1666667 * ($lat2 - $lat1)), 2) + (115.1666667 * pow(($lng2 - $lng1) * cos($lat2 / 57.3)), 2)), 0.5)

Comment: I am not a PHP expert but at least this is the formula I am using to get the distance from 2 different locations. Get 2 real locations that you know the distance, apply the formula, always take care about km to meter and so on and I think you must be ok. Another advice is that when you go into the math, physics part of programming you have to be really careful and have some basic knowledge regarding some facts. I believe that if you play around with this formula you ll get it. @holyredbeard later when I find some time Ill convert the formula to your needs

Comment: @holyredbeard answer updated with the code you wanted. I believe that it is quite complete and understandable

Comment: I know this is an old stack but I found this script and when I use it, it returns me 0.00. Doesn't matter which lat & long i insert. Can anyone please help me.

Comment: @DanielLundahl I just run again the code and was fine. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @JimmyKane I know my variables has values with lat and long, but printing $dist after the $dist = acos(..... returns 0. Something gets wrong while setting the $dist variable.

Comment: @DanielLundahl make a question please with how you use this algorithm and I ll be pleased to help you. Ask it first pasting the code you use and then mention here the link. I cannot help you via comments and I don't understand what your variables means, what structure and types they have. It's very abstract.

Comment: @JimmyKane I've now asked a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638724/issue-with-distance-calculation

Answer (score 4):

I have this function, it calculates the difference between points 1 and 2. The function returns miles, so I multiplied by 1.609344 to convert it to km.

```
<?php
function lat_long_dist($lat1, $long1, $lat2, $long2){
    $pi = pi();
    $x  = sin($lat1 * $pi/180) * 
          sin($lat2 * $pi/180) + 
          cos($lat1 * $pi/180) * 
          cos($lat2 * $pi/180) * 
          cos(($long2 * $pi/180) - ($long1 * $pi/180));
    $x  = atan((sqrt(1 - pow($x, 2))) / $x);
    return (1.852 * 60.0 * (($x/$pi) * 180)) / 1.609344;
}

$people   = array();
$people[] = array(56.34342, 49.324523);
$people[] = array(57.49544, 47.421524);
$people[] = array(56.74612, 48.722323);

foreach($people as $person){
    $lat1 = $person[0];
    $lon1 = $person[1];
    $distance = lat_long_dist($lat1, $lon1, 56.35343, 49.342343) * 1.609344;
    if($distance <= 2){
        echo "$i is within 2km!\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for sharing your code! Will try it out immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Use Pythagoras to find the distance between target and each person in turn and check whether it is less than 2 km. If x,y are the coordinates of the target and p,q the coordinates of one of the persons the distance between the two is:
((x-p)^2 + (y-q)^2)^(1/2)
The ^ symbol means "raised to the power of".

Comment: That works if they're points in a plane, but if they're geographical coordinates (points on a sphere), you need to use the Haversine function instead.