# Issue with distance calculation

Tags: php, function

I found this function in another question at stackoverflow([Check if coordinates is within a specific distance from other coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087076/check-if-coordinates-is-within-a-specific-distance-from-other-coordinates/14091657?noredirect=1#comment32699010_14091657)) and all it returns me is 0.00. I don't know why it doesn't work since it seems to work for others. Please, I don't see what's wrong, can you?

```
function calculate_distance($busCoord, $spot){
    $lat1 = $busCoord[0]; //40.4167754
    $lng1 = $busCoord[1]; //3.7037901999999576
    $lat2 = $spot[0]; //40.466173
    $lng2 = $spot[1]; //3.6706590000000006
    $pi = 3.1414926;
    $rad = doubleval($pi/180.0);

    $lon1 = $lng1*$rad;
    $lat1 = $lat1*$rad; 
    $lon2 = $lng2*$rad; 
    $lat2 = $lat2*$rad; 
    $theta = $lng2 - $lng1; 

    $dist = acos(sin($lat1) * sin($lat2) + cos($lat1) * cos($lat2) * cos($theta)); 

    if ($dist < 0)
        $dist += $pi


    $miles = doubleval($dist * 69.1); 
    $inches = doubleval($miles * 63360); 
    $km  =  doubleval($dist * 114.1666667);

    $dist = sprintf( "%.2f",$dist); 
    $miles = sprintf( "%.2f",$miles); 
    $inches = sprintf( "%.2f",$inches); 
    $km = sprintf( "%.2f",$km);
    //Here you can return whatever you please
    return $km;
}
```

Comment: Careful, your value of Pi is wrong (3.14159 instead of 3.14149). I don't know if the result is hugely impacted or not (I haven't tried your function) but it might get some bias. Use one of these instead: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pi.php

Comment: Also, you are missing a semicolon at line `$dist += $pi`

Comment: You copied the code wrong! put them in two separate files and do `diff  file1.php file2.php` you are missing the doubleevals when you define the double lon,lats.

Comment: @DanielLundahl, for what it's worth, this code outputs `2.88` for me.

Comment: @JérémieAstori thanks for correcting the pi , and the op copied the code wrong from my answer.